# Pandas: Loop through rows to update column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Here is sample dataframe look like:

```
>>> df
  point    x      y
0  0.1   NaN    NaN
1  0.2   NaN    NaN
2  0.3   5.0    NaN
3  0.4   NaN    NaN
4  0.5   NaN    1.0
5  0.6   NaN    NaN
6  0.7   1.0    1.0
7  0.8   NaN    NaN
8  0.9   NaN    NaN
9  1.1   NaN    NaN
10 1.2   NaN    NaN
11 1.3   NaN    NaN
12 1.4   NaN    2.0
13 1.5   NaN    NaN
14 1.6   NaN    NaN
15 1.7   NaN    NaN
16 0.1   NaN    NaN
17 0.2   NaN    NaN
18 0.3   NaN    NaN
19 0.4   NaN    NaN
20 0.5   NaN    NaN
21 0.6   2.0    NaN
22 0.7   NaN    NaN
23 1.1   NaN    NaN
```

From this dataFrame I want to update `point` value. Condition is when `x` or `y` is not `NaN` immediate next value of `point` will be replaced by previous `point` value afterthat next point value should be reindexed(**cycle .1 to .6**). eg. in row index(2) when `point=0.3, x=5.0` So, the next `point` value should be also **0.3 instead of 0.4**, Then in row index(4) point=0.5 will be replaced by 0.4(continue recursively)

OUTPUT I want:

```
  point    x      y
0  0.1   NaN    NaN
1  0.2   NaN    NaN
2  0.3   5.0    NaN
3  0.3   NaN    NaN
4  0.4   NaN    1.0
5  0.4   NaN    NaN
6  0.5   1.0    1.0
7  0.5   NaN    NaN
8  0.6   NaN    NaN
9  1.1   NaN    NaN
10 1.2   NaN    NaN
11 1.3   NaN    NaN
12 1.4   NaN    2.0
13 1.4   NaN    NaN
14 1.5   NaN    NaN
15 1.6   NaN    NaN
16 0.1   NaN    NaN
17 0.2   NaN    NaN
18 0.3   NaN    NaN
19 0.4   NaN    NaN
20 0.5   NaN    NaN
21 0.6   2.0    NaN
22 0.6   NaN    NaN
23 1.1   NaN    NaN
```

Code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['point'] = df.groupby() #Don't know how should I approach
```

Comment: Now the problem is clear and short (+1 for that).

Comment: Your cycle is an alternate of 0. and 1.?

Comment: For example cycle: `0.1-0.6` ,`1.1-1.6` ,`2.1-2.6` and so on. In between `.1-.6` cycle any value might appear several times consecutively but index should be followed like 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 1.1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try that:

```
mask = df[['x', 'y']].any(axis=1).shift(1, fill_value=False)
point = df['point'].astype(int)
group = point.sub(point.shift(1)).ne(0).cumsum()

df['point'] = df['point'].sub(mask.groupby(group).cumsum().div(10))
```

```
>>> df
    point    x    y
0     0.1  NaN  NaN
1     0.2  NaN  NaN
2     0.3  5.0  NaN
3     0.3  NaN  NaN
4     0.4  NaN  1.0
5     0.4  NaN  NaN
6     0.5  1.0  1.0
7     0.5  NaN  NaN
8     0.6  NaN  NaN
9     1.1  NaN  NaN
10    1.2  NaN  NaN
11    1.3  NaN  NaN
12    1.4  NaN  2.0
13    1.4  NaN  NaN
14    1.5  NaN  NaN
15    1.6  NaN  NaN
16    0.1  NaN  NaN
17    0.2  NaN  NaN
18    0.3  NaN  NaN
19    0.4  NaN  NaN
20    0.5  NaN  NaN
21    0.6  2.0  NaN
22    0.6  NaN  NaN
23    1.1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thaks for this. But still it didn't solve my problem. `point` value should be also reindexed. For instance, in row index(4), `point` should be 0.4 instead of 0.5. There is a cycle `_.1 to _.6` it must be followed. Please take a look on my sample output.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried something. First created some dataframe for my self. I tried to follow your txt (was little confusing for me non native speaker). I wrote something. It is not very generic but it should work for your case and with this idea I think you can solve problems.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = np.zeros((8, 3))
f = np.random.randint(8, size=8)

df[:, 0] = f
df[:, 1:] = np.nan
df[1, 1] = 5
df[3, 1:] = 4

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.iloc[i, 1:].notnull()).any()&(df.iloc[i, 1:].isnull()).any():
        print(i)
        df[0][i+1] = df[0][i]
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't relate these codes with my given problem.

Comment: Untill loop it is just creating some dataframe as I do not have your data. The loop is doing your idea.